# iOS, Tab bar on left side, navigation controller on right side. How to implement?

Tags: ios

I have an iPad app that will have tab bar on left side, navigation controller on right side. How to implement? Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the wireframe of what you needed

Comment: I think the best way is to create a custom UIViewController and add them as childViewController, you can find some tutorial on Google

Comment: @Macro, any way to do it in StoryBoard?

Comment: @Ramesh There is no on hand wireframe now. I need a split view on iPad with its "master" width can be customized. Besides, in its detail view, it shows an navigation bar at the top.

Comment: I think I got a demo here: http://dwz.cn/tYak6